# How do I SetEnv only for a specific IP in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to set some environment only for a specific IP,how to do that in Apache?

Answer (score 3):

See the [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#SetEnvIf) directive, which defines environment variables based on attributes of the request, such as `Remote_Addr` (the IP address of the client making the request)...

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^192\.168\.0\. LOCAL_LAN=1
```

...or `Server_Addr` (the IP address of the server on which the request was received)...

```
SetEnvIf Server_Addr ^192\.168\.0\.1$ SITE_PROFILE=PRODUCTION
SetEnvIf Server_Addr ^192\.168\.0\.2$ SITE_PROFILE=DEVELOPMENT
```

Note that the second argument to `SetEnvIf` is a regular expression, so be extra mindful if you're tempted to use bare IPs, as a pattern like 192.168.1.1 (while looking a lot cleaner than escaping dots as I do above) will also end up matching 192.168.101.10.

**UPDATE:**

`SetEnvIf` can't access QUERY_STRING, but [per the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#SetEnvIf):-

> See the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive of [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for extra information on how to match your query string.

So something like...

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)debug=
RewriteRule . - [E=LOCAL_LAN_AND_DEBUG:1]
```

Comment: How can I do it if there's a `debug` parameter in the querystring?

Comment: Per the docs, you would need to use mod_rewrite instead. Example added to answer above.

Comment: What does `. -` mean in `. - [E=LOCAL_LAN_AND_DEBUG:1]` ? Also does `LOCAL_LAN_AND_DEBUG:1` set both `LOCAL_LAN` and `DEBUG` to `1`?

Comment: BTW,isn't querystring also stored in environment variables?

Comment: I just tried,and the environment variable is NOT set though..

Comment: `. -` tells mod_rewrite to match all URLs (`.`), but not perform any URL substitution (`-`). `[E=LOCAL_LAN_AND_DEBUG:1]` sets `LOCAL_LAN_AND_DEBUG` to `1`, but you could use `[E=LOCAL_LAN:1,E=DEBUG:1]` to set both `LOCAL_LAN` and `DEBUG` to `1`. Also made an error in my example above - `RewriteCond` needs environment variables to written as `%{VARIABLE}` not `VARIABLE` -- I've updated the example.

Answer (score 2):

In [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#unnop) you can set an environment variable for a single IP address or a whole subnet using CIDR notation. Eg.:

```
<If "-R '93.184.216.34'">
  SetEnv myvar1=example
</If>

<If "-R '93.184.216.0/24'">
  SetEnv myvar2=subnet
</If>
```

These can also be combined with logical operators inside the expression:

```
<If "-R '93.184.216.34' || 
     -R '192.0.32.0/24'">
  SetEnv myvar3=both
</If>
```